# How to convert Unit to String in kotlin (UPD doesn't work after adding synchronous code)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have function which doesn't return any:

```
   fun getName(name:String){

        val requestUrl =
            "https://api/app/getherp"
        val resRequest =object :JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, requestUrl,null,
            { response ->

            },
            { error ->
              
            }
        )
        queue.add(resRequest)
    }
```

I want return value getName's function like this:

```
fun getNorm(name: String): String {
        return getName(name)
    }
```

but I get error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
String
Found:
Unit
```

I know that if I add `.toString` to `return getName(name)` - this is not enough. Because in this case I get as result `kotlin.Unit` . What have I to do?? Thank you

**UPD: as advice here I added synchronous code. But result is the same.**
My code is now:

```
fun getName(
       name: String,
        requestResult: (res: JSONObject) -> Unit,
        requestError: ((err: String) -> Unit)? = null
    ) {

val requestUrl = "https://api/app/getherp"

        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, null,
            { response ->
               requestResult(response)

            },
            { error ->
              
                requestError?.invoke(error.toString());
            }
        ) {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                return getAuthHeaders()
            }
        }
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
```

and I call this function like this:

```
fun getNamePers(
    name: String, result: (res: JSONObject) -> Unit,
    error: ((err: String) -> Unit)? = null
) {
   MyClass.getName(name, result, error)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: that code isn't synchronous, it returns at a later point in time

Comment: @ a_local_nobody , I have to do this code is synchronous?

Comment: @Julia Your assumption, that this would all run on the same thread doesn't apply... because the `String` which you want is only available in the callback of the `JsonObjectRequest` (in case the request had no error). Please check the documentation, which I've linked in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Function   `getNorm` should return String but it returns `getName` and expects getName function to return a String, but `getName` function doesn't return anything which is why it is giving unit error, either remove the return type String, or return the string which you need from `getName`

Comment: thank you for advice. But in both of these cases i get the same result

Comment: This is because the asynchronous execution of `JsonObjectRequest` had not been considered. There may be some learning curve involved, but it's not that difficult, once having understood what is actually going on.

Comment: exactly the async flow should be considered for getting the result and @Julia  check for async execution for functions and for quick resolution I suggest you to create a interface and implement that function wherever you need and pass the instance to the class of async function and when you get the result call the method to set the result data.

Answer (score 2):

`fun getName(name:String)` would need to return `String` in a synchronous manner. As this doesn't seem to be possible with `JsonObjectRequest`, I'd question the whole approach. `fun getNorm(name: String): String` also appears quite superfluous, as it only wraps the other one method.

You'd need to move your code into `{ response -> ... }` - or call a method from there.

See [Asynchronous Programming Techniques](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/async-programming.html) for a more detailed explanation.

When setting a few [break-points](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints), the order of execution merely explains itself.